How to Set Up a Puppeteer Grid Similar to Selenium Grid?
I'm currently scraping a few sites using Selenium Grid, which is working well. I've configured my Selenium Grid at http://seleniumgrid.api.company-site.com:4444 with 10 nodes.
However, I'm facing limitations with certain sites, particularly in handling events with Selenium. To overcome these issues, I want to use Puppeteer. I've managed to scrape sites with Puppeteer, but the testing runs in a new popup browser window (similar to Selenium when not using the company site).
I'd like to set up an environment for Puppeteer that's similar to Selenium Grid.
Can someone guide me on how to set up a Puppeteer grid similar to Selenium Grid?
const browser = await puppeteer.connect({
browserWSEndpoint: SBR_WS_ENDPOINT,
});
//rest of the code.
